# Nexus 6P Heating Issues

Tags: overheating, nexus-6p

I have a Nexus 6P 64 GB which is just 4 months old. I feel that the phone is getting hot more than normal, mainly the display. When I do browsing say for 10-15 mins or shoot videos (4K) 2-3 mins or take HDR photos 10-15 photos in succession, the phone gets hot from every nook and corner. My local service center is not very high tech. The only solution they suggested is to flash the OS. I do not to what extent this is going to help. I did nt buy the phone from Google Store but from other online partners in India.  I sought help of people around here or users of Nexus 6P about their experience.

Thanks.

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: Question is if other Nexus 6p gets too hot as well or not ;-)

Comment: No answer or comments means, this is not a known problem with other Nexus 6Ps???

Comment: @V.B my Nexus 6P becomes hot sometimes too. Should be normal.

Comment: This might be of interest: https://support.google.com/nexus/answer/3333708

Comment: Hi Guys. After updating to Nougat 7.0 the problem seems to be gone now. I am happy with the phone now. No more heating issues.

Answer (score 0):

I recently bought a nexus 6p myself and upgraded it to Nougat (Android 7.0).
It burns like a stove after playing 10 minutes of any 3D games (in my case, Walking Dead: No man's land), and that's both before and after the system update.
I think the following article explains the reason pretty well, it's all about the processor:
http://www.androidheadlines.com/2015/10/huawei-nexus-6p-good-bad-ugly.html

I tried wrapping an ice pack with a towel under my phone while using it and it helped a lot.
I'm not sure if that's good idea though because people say that it will definitely cause condensation inside the device and void the warranty.

Answer (score 0):

Please ensure that you have a fan with a cool cloth(ice water soaked) draped over it blowing on your 6P. Do not use the phone outdoors for long periods, use mainly in air condition and never leave in your car.